# How to perform a subroutine every 5 seconds?

Tags: applescript-objc

I have a subroutine to check if a disk is mounted,
I would like to know how do I make this subroutine always run every 5 seconds.

thanks in advance!

```
on checkMyDiskIsMounted()
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            if exists disk "myDisk" then
                --do anything
                else
                --do anything
            end if
        end tell
    end checkMyDiskIsMounted
```

Comment: Repeat with a delay of 5 seconds?

Comment: Since you are using AppleScriptObjC the best would probably be to not use repeated checks at all and instead add an observer for `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using things like AppleScript's `delay` command, a shell utility such as `sleep`, or even a tight repeat loop should all be avoided, as those tend to block the user interface while they are running.

A repeating timer could be used to periodically poll, but instead of wasting time continually checking for something that may or may not happen, [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) can be used, as it provides notifications for exactly this kind of thing (amongst others).  The way this works is your application registers for the particular notifications that it is interested in, and the specified handler is called when (if) the event occurs.

Note that the following script includes statements so that it can be run from the Script Editor as an example - observers are added to the application instance, and will stick around until they are removed or the application is quit:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

on run -- or whatever initialization handler
    # set up notifications
    tell current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's notificationCenter
        its addObserver:me selector:"volumeMounted:" |name|:(current application's NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification) object:(missing value)
        its addObserver:me selector:"volumeUnmounted:" |name|:(current application's NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification) object:(missing value)
    end tell
end run

on volumeMounted:aNotification -- do something on mount
    set volumeName to (NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey of aNotification's userInfo) as text
    display notification "The volume " & quoted form of volumeName & " was mounted." with title "Volume mounted" sound name "Hero" -- or whatever
end volumeMounted:

on volumeUnmounted:aNotification -- do something on unmount
    set volumeName to (NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey of aNotification's userInfo) as text
    display notification "The volume " & quoted form of volumeName & " was unmounted." with title "Volume unmounted" sound name "Funk" -- or whatever
end volumeUnmounted:
```

Comment: A stupid question, how could I call this subroutine in other parts of my code?

Comment: The handlers are called by the system (via the observer), and are passed a notification object.  Depending on exactly what you are wanting to do, they could call a common handler.

Comment: What I want is to enable a button as soon as it detects that the partition has been mounted, otherwise the button remains hidden.

Comment: Create a utility handler that (un)hides a button.  In the notification handler(s), check that the (un)mounted volume is what you are looking for, and if so then call the button handler.

Answer (score 1):

Four options:

1. A repeat loop with delay as suggested by matt

   ```
   repeat
       -- code
       delay 5
   end repeat
   ```
2. A (stay open) applet with `idle` handler

   ```
   on run
       -- do intialiations
   end run

   on idle
       -- code
       return 5
   end idle
   ```
3. An AppleScriptObjC notification like suggested by red_menace
4. A launchd agent observing the `/Volumes` folder

In favor of option 3 and 4 which inexpensively notify about a change the first two options which poll periodically are discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try.